# C++ Source code errors

Tags: c++, arrays, file, c++11, vector

Can someone tell me how to fix the errors?Also would be better if I change array to vector for c++11 ? I will get any advantages?Also can someone tell me if there is any way to improve my code ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//#define long long 100000000;
//#define int 1000;

using namespace std;
void ts1(int *zone);
void ts2();
void ts3();
int p,n,m;
struct lazer{
    int x;
    int y;
    int direction;

};
//int z[4]={1,1,1,1}
int main()
{
   // int p,n;
   // long z;
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("input.txt");
    file >> p;
    file >>n>>m;
    lazer Bem[m];
   // long * sir = new long[2*n];
   // long sir[2*n] ;
    int *zone[n][n];
    for (int i=0;i< n;i++)
        for (int j=0;j< n;j++)
            file>>zone[i][j];
        //file >> sir[i];

    for (int k=0;k<m;k++){
            file >> Bem[k].x;
            file >> Bem[k].y;
            file >> Bem[k].direction;
    }
    file.close();
    for(int z1=0;z1<m;z1++){
        switch(Bem[z1].direction){
            case 1:
                for(int zt=n-Bem[z1].x;zt<n;z1++)
                {

                    zone[zt][Bem[z1].y]=zone[zt][Bem[z1].y] -1;
                }
        }

    }


    if (p==1)ts1(zone);
    else ts2();
   // else ts3();
//    delete [] sir;
    return 0;
}
void ts1(int *zone){
    int gropi=0;
    static int* mutari[8][2]={{-1,0}, {-1, -1}, {0, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}};//{{-1,0},{0,1},{1,0},{0,-1}}
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            for(int z=0;z<8;z++){
                int ni=i+mutari[z][0];
                int nj=j+mutari[z][1];
                if(zone[i][j] <= zone[ni][nj])gropi++;
            }

        }

    }

}
void ts2(){
    cout << "d";
}
void ts3(){
    cout << "d";
}
```

**Errors:**

```
void ts1(int **zone){
    int gropi=0;
    static int mutari[8][2]={{-1,0}, {-1, -1}, {0, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}};//{{-1,0},{0,1},{1,0},{0,-1}}
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            for(int z=0;z<8;z++){
                int ni=i+mutari[z][0];
                int nj=j+mutari[z][1];
                if(zone[i][j] <= zone[ni][nj])gropi++;
            }

        }

    }
    cout <<gropi;
}
```

at this part `cout <<gropi;` will make the exe stop.Why?

Comment: `zone[i][j]` is a pointer (an `int*`), as is `mutari[z][0]`. Did you mean to declare `int zone[n][n]` and `int mutari[8][2]`?

Comment: @molbdnilo yes thanks dude,what about the error from (p==1)ts1(zone);How to pass as paramereter the entire pointer?

Comment: Arrays are not pointers (and pointers are not arrays). You can't pass multi-dimensional "VLA" arrays (which aren't standard anyway) as parameters, you'll need an array of pointers. I recommend that you use `std::vector` instead of arrays.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks, but how an array is not a pointer? int*ds=int ds[]

Comment: An array can be implicitly converted into a pointer to its first element. That doesn't mean that arrays are pointers, just like the fact that an int can be converted to a float doesn't mean that ints are floats.

Comment: `int *zone[n][n];` is not standard C++ when `n` is not a constant expression (but is supported as a compiler extension in some compilers). Instead of an array, you should use a `std::vector`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ok thanks dudes for help

Comment: @crashmstr Ok thanks dudes for help

Comment: @crashmstr Can you also tell me why cout <<gropi; makes the program stops please?

Comment: @rares are you sure it stops there (you stepped through in a debugger and that line specifically is the problem)?

Comment: @rares also, it sounds like that should be a new question, since the other issues were fixed with an answer below.

Comment: @crashmstr on debug it says some reference to ni and nj but I don't understand why cuz I use only integers,the static int array I think did not affect the problem

Comment: Check `ni` and `nj` for being out of bounds for `zone` (hint: when `i=0` and `z=0`, `mutari[0][0]` is `-1`, `0 + -1` is `-1`, which is never allowed for an array access).

Comment: @crashmstr Thanks a lot, I edit main post and make all first column and line 1000 and increse the size of the array with 1/1 but it still crash

Comment: @rares by making that change, you've invalidated the accepted answer. Instead, you should roll back that change and ask a new question with the updated code.

Comment: @crashmstr Ok,I put it on the old version but I need 7 days for a new question because this has -4,can we move to chat?

Comment: with 1 reputation I can't go to chat...

Comment: @rares debugging is a critical skill for a developer. Step through and see what happens. On the line that crashes, look at what is happening and what values are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not gone thru your full code, but i had a look in `main()` method.
and i found few issues like;

```
lazer Bem[m];
```

you can not declare array like this, because it requires exact size during its compilation. you need to use pointers to allocate memory dynamically.

I have done few modification in your `main()` method;

```
//int z[4]={1,1,1,1}
int main()
{
   // int p,n;
   // long z;
    std::ifstream file("input.txt");

    file >> p;
    file >>n>>m;

    lazer* Bem = new lazer[m];
    int **zone = new int*[n];

    for (int i=0;i< n;i++)
    {
        zone[i] = new int[n];
        for (int j=0;j< n;j++)
        {
            file>>zone[i][j];
        }
    }
        //file >> sir[i];

    for (int k=0;k<m;k++){
            file >> Bem[k].x;
            file >> Bem[k].y;
            file >> Bem[k].direction;
    }
    file.close();
    for(int z1=0;z1<m;z1++){
        switch(Bem[z1].direction){
            case 1:
                for(int zt=n-Bem[z1].x;zt<n;z1++)
                {

                    zone[zt][Bem[z1].y]=zone[zt][Bem[z1].y] -1;
                }
        }

    }


    if (p==1)ts1(zone);
    else ts2();
   // else ts3();
//    delete [] sir;
    return 0;
}
```

you can modify other method similarly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude :)

Comment: but if I write  cout <<gropi; in void ts1 at the end the exe stops